Confused about the uniform distribution of p-values under the null hypothesis
I'm currently taking an introductory bioinformatics course, and I'm confused about the uniform distribution of p-values under the null hypothesis (when the null hypothesis is true).
It's been shown and discussed extensively that, under the correct conditions, p-values are uniformly distributed when the null hypothesis holds, as explained in this post: Why are p-values uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis?.
My confusion is more about the intuition and practical meaning behind this idea.
For example, let's consider a simple (albeit discrete) scenario: a coin toss. If the probability of getting heads (denoted as "1") is $p = 0.3$, and we perform $1000$ tosses, we expect the see most cases where we get around $300$ heads. So, we would expect that in most cases the p-values will be around $P(X < 300)$ (left-tailed p-value, where $X$ is a binomial($1000$, $p$) variable).
However, this seems contradictory to the idea that p-values should be uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis. If p-values are uniform, shouldn't all p-values be equally likely, not clustered around a certain value?
Could someone explain why this uniform distribution still holds in this example, or if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental?
I've ran the following simulation as an example:
library(ggplot2)

n_experiments <- 100000     # Number of experiments (coin tosses)
n_trials <- 100000          # Number of trials per experiment
p <- 0.3                 # Probability of getting a '1' (success)

# Simulate experiments
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
results <- rbinom(n_experiments, n_trials, p)  # Number of 1's in each experiment

# Calculate p-values for each experiment
p_values <- sapply(results, function(x) pbinom(x, n_trials, p))

# Create a data frame for plotting
df <- data.frame(Experiment = 1:n_experiments, 
                 Number_of_1s = results, 
                 p_value = p_values)

# Plot histogram of the number of '1's
ggplot(df, aes(x = Number_of_1s)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = 'skyblue', color = 'black') +
  labs(title = "Histogram of the Number of 1's in 100 Experiments", 
       x = "Number of 1's", 
       y = "Frequency") +
  theme_minimal()

# Plot histogram of p-values
ggplot(df, aes(x = p_value)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, fill = 'coral', color = 'black') +
  labs(title = "Histogram of p-values in 100 Experiments", 
       x = "p-value", 
       y = "Frequency") +
  theme_minimal()

And have found the following expected results which feel contradictory to me, the distribution of the values is not uniform, but the distribution of p-values is.



Your distribution corresponds to what hypothesis test?

You may want to edit your graphs; they are labeled as "in 100 experiments", but you did 1000 coin tosses, and 100,000 experiments (repeated 1000 tosses). "in 100,000 repeats of 100 coin tosses"?

Could you be more specific about the "clustering" you see?  I see only a histogram of a sample from an approximately uniform distribution.  It is indeed a little strange, but not due to anything that would deserve to be called "clustering." What is strange is that the variation in heights is too large and the labeling is suspect: as @jginestet points out, this is not a histogram of only 100 p-values!

@whuber, I would not pay too much attention to the bins at 0 & 1; yes they indeed are much too low (for a uniform), but they are most likely half-width bins (0.005 width, vs. 0.01 for all the others). W/o these, it looks uniform enough (to me).

@jginestet I pay no attention to those bins--that's a well-known "feature" of some bad binning procedures.  The rest is not uniform enough, because a typical standard deviation of a count near 900 is 30 and many of these counts differ by four or five times that amount.  // It's worth noting that these are not p-values, btw.

This experiment is erroneous. One (minor) reason is that it doesn't compute p-values: it just computes a probability integral transform.  The major reason can be found by making one tiny change and re-running the code.  Set n_trials to a smaller value, such as n_trials = 100.  Ponder the (very strange looking) histogram that results.

Note that uniformity under $H_0$ strictly only applies under the conditions that the test statistic is continuous and you have a point null. If the test statistic is discrete, the distribution of p-values is also discrete. If the null is composite the p-values under the null will only be uniform in part of the null-space. In either case the cdf of the distribution of p-values should remain $\leq$ the y=x line (equivalently to the right of it). This is addressed in numerous places on site

Your p-value plot looks pretty uniform to me...
Now for intuition, if the null is true, and if you chose $\alpha=.05$ (tradition), you would expect 5% of the p-values to be below .05. So $P(p\le.05)=.05$.
But if instead you used $\alpha=.1$, you would expect 10% of the p-values to be less than .1. So $P(p\le.1)=.1$.
Similarly, if we changed $\alpha$ to $.2$, $.3$, $.5$, etc, we would expect $P(p\le.2)=.2, P(p\le.3)=.3, P(p\le.5)=.5, etc.$
So we have $P(p\le x)=x$ for all $x$'s. What kind of function is $P(x)$? Well that is just the CDF of a uniform distribution, $P(x)=x$. Hence the distribution of p-values under the null must be uniform.
Now, what may confuse you, is that you confuse the histogram of counts (which is binomial, which in your case looks normal-ish), with the histogram of p-values. Since the null is true, the histogram of counts looks exactly as would be expected under the null; and therefore the histogram of p-values will be just as expected under the null, i.e. uniform. Counts measure how often you drew, say, heads. The p-value measures how compatible these counts are with the null hypothesis. Two related things, but very different.
Yes, it may be disconcerting to think that, under the null, you have an equal chance of obtaining any p-value. We would love for the p-value to be 1 under this condition... But then confidence levels, significance, power, etc. would not work as expected... So, under the null, you can essentially say that the p-value does not tell you anything. But if the null is false, it then starts to tell a story.
Edit (and corrections) 9/19/2024
This edit is the result of an exchange of comments I had with whuber, on this topic. Based on his remarks, and me digging more into the simulations, I realized that the question was in fact much deeper than I first thought (+1), that the OP’s intuition was in fact absolutely correct, and that the answer, or insight, was in fact more surprising than I expected (yes, at first, I thought “p-value uniformly distributed; but of course!”, and flat histograms were rushing in front of my eyes, such as one can find on this nice interactive simulation. https://shiny.ieis.tue.nl/MOOC/assignment_1/
At first glance, the OP’s histogram of p-values looked to me “flat-ish” enough, and so I declared it “uniform”. I was wrong, and whuber corrected me on this, with good reasons; the variability in the histogram bars was much too large to be truly uniform. It may look “flat-ish”, but uniform it is not.
Whuber also mentioned that what the OP computed as p-values were not really p-values. It turns out that the OP truly computes correct p-values, but not for a 2-tailed exact binomial test, but instead a 1-tailed exact binomial, for a null of $p_0=.3$ against an alternative of $p_0>.3$. Since the null was true, one would expect a uniform histogram? Where was the disconnect? So I decided to play with my own simulation.
As luck would have it, instead of using 1000 coin tosses, as the OP described in his text, or using 100,000 coin tosses as the OP did in his code, I used only 100. This is the histogram I obtained;

Definitively not uniform! In fact, that shape is exactly as the OP’s intuition would dictate. But... it is supposed to be uniform, by the very definition of what p-values should do under the null (i.e. having $100\alpha \%$ chance of being less than $\alpha$, for all values of $\alpha$.
Now whuber also made the excellent suggestion to look at the ECDF, instead of the histogram. So, this is the ECDF I got (in orange is the identity line);

A stair-step ECDF, but “perfectly” following the identity line (it is not perfect; e.g. for p=0.1646, its frequency is .01699%, but the scale of the graph is small enough that it looks “perfect”). So, is the distributions of p-values uniform or not? If one looks at the histogram it is obviously not? But if one looks at the ECDF is obviously is? What is happening?
What is happening is that, for discrete distributions, the distribution of p-values is also discrete. After all, for 100 coin tosses, one could expect at most 100 possible different counts, and so only 100 possible different p-values. In fact, in my simulation, I only got 40 different possible counts, and 40 different p-values. So clearly, some counts (say around 30) will be much more abundant than others (e.g. around 1 -where I had none- or around 11 -where I only had 1). So that is not uniform, or is it? (as the OP rightfully questioned).
But, the gaps between obtained counts are also not uniform. As we can see on the ECDF graph, the gaps (or steps) are very small at either end, but very large in the middle (because we have many more trials which ended up with that count/p-value). And the gaps compensate the clustering of p-values as they should, to give a uniform CDFs, or rather as much a uniform distribution as possible with a discrete distribution. This becomes obvious in a plot of only the unique p-values, and their relative frequencies.

Now, the OP, in his simulation, used 100000 coin tosses. With that many coin tosses per trial, the discrete nature of the situation is greatly diminished (there will be a larger number of observed counts, and thus p-values). And so, its histogram could look “flat-ish” (sufficiently to fool me). But it was not uniform.
A parallel discussion was also taking place wrt to what caused this. Some were of the opinion that it was an artifact of the histogram. I do not share this point of view; yes, the histogram adds additional artifacts to the display of the p-values, but if anything, it smoothes the situation. So I  plotted a bar chart of the p-values; each bar shows 1 and only 1 of the unique p-values obtained in the simulation (therefore, no more binning – but the spacing along the x-axis is meaningless).

I also added the results of a simulation done with 1000 coin tosses (to get an intermediate point), and the distribution function of the binomial B(100,000,.3), because it looks eerily similar. If the distribution were discrete, and uniform, we would expect all p-values to have equal probabilities; they clearly do not. In fact, they behave as questioned by the OP. As can be seen from the bar charts, if anything, the histogram hides this very clear non-uniformity, as shown on the next graphs, showing the histograms of p-values for the 3 simulations (100, 1000, 100000 coin tosses), and for 3 different bin counts (21, 101, 999).



So 21 bins almost hides the non-uniformity (except for 100 tosses), 101 hides the issue for 100,000 tosses but not the other 2, and 999 bins does not hide things too much (but still distorts it). So yes, there is aliasing of sort, when we sample a discrete, non-uniformly spaced, non uniform distribution, with another discrete distribution (this one uniformly spaced). But the net contribution of this is that, while it obscures/misrepresent the true distribution, it actually “smoothes” out the effects (this sub-sampling is in fact sort of a convolution, “flattening” things). And indeed, the higher the sampling frequency, the less significant the effect is.
On the other hand, the CDF  is uniformly distributed, as the graph below shows (done for coin tosses of 100, 1000, and 100,000)

As we can see, the CDF is stair-stepped (which "disappears for 100,000 coin tosses), but follow a straight line, as best as a discrete function can.
So the true cause of the situation is that in fact the distribution of p-values is not uniform, at all. Or more formally, the PMF of the sampling distribution of p-values is not uniform. It is in fact binomially distributed, as intuited by the OP, and as should be logically expected. But, the CDF of the sampling distribution of the p-values follows a uniform distribution (as uniform as a discrete CDF can be). This combination of non-uniform PMF, but uniform CDF was surprising, to me at least. The histogram only blurs this, by adding its artifacts, but is not the cause.
In the end, the p-value is uniformly distributed only for continuous distributions. But, the CDF of the p-values is uniform for both continuous and discrete distributions. (all of this, of course, iff the null is true).
Btw, this paper, P-values are random variables by Murdoch et al (2008) touched on exactly the same issue. Their conclusion was that for discrete distributions, “it is no longer true that the distribution of p-values is uniform, ... , and the histograms are not useful”. I certainly can not disagree with this, but would add that, as pointed by whuber, the CDF’s are useful.
QUESTION?; given that a CDF could be uniform, while its PMF is not, this could occur for other discrete distributions. This may also happen for normal approximations (e.g. $\chi^2$) to discrete distributions. Is there a term for this phenomenon (CDF follows a certain distribution, but not the PMF)? If there is no such term, shouldn’t there be? Cumulatively uniform? Or cumulatively normal? Or ??
TL;DR; the OP is correct. For discrete distributions, the PMF is not uniformly distributed, but the CDF is. Histograms are not useful, but CDF's are.

Distribution testing convincingly demonstrates this histogram is definitely not uniform.  There is a subtle number-theoretic reason: a form of digital aliasing occurs when slicing these Binomial probabilities into 100 bins.  It causes much greater variation within bins together with excess negative correlation.  The problem is with the histogram (as well with the misunderstanding of p-values reflected in the code).  If you were to plot the ECDF of the "p-values," it would look beautifully uniform.

Thanks for the clarification; indeed, aliasing does occur when sampling 100,000 p-values into 100 bins;  definitively not Nyquist. I may think of editing the answer based on your comment (with due credit).

The issue isn't the number of p-values: it's that (1) these are Binomial probabilities, not p-values; (2) there are only a few hundred of them with appreciable probabilities; (3) they are unequally spaced; and (4) therefore only extremely coarse histograms will be uniform.  Plotting the ECDF is a superior way to assess this distribution.

This is honestly amazing. I would like to say that I apologize for my inconsistency in posting and overlooks, but seems like this led you through an interesting rabbit hole, and to a very thorough answer. Bravo and thank you.
I think I will leave the post with the inconsistencies, feel free to add it if you desire.
also many thanks to @whuber for pointing everything out. I am left with the question though - why does this not happen in the continuous case?

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435833/the-distribution-of-the-p-values-under-the-null-hypothesis-is-uniform0-1.

This experiment will confuse anyone because these are not p-values and they aren't supposed to be uniform.  More importantly, and of greater interest IMHO, it illustrates a subtle pitfall with histograms that has tripped up many people.  See What is this "phenomenon" called? for a related example.

The code estimates the cumulative Binomial probabilities $$B(x,n,p) = \sum_{k=0}^x\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ (for $x = 10^5$ and $p=0.3$) by drawing random values $X$ from this distribution and returning $Q = B(X,n,p)$ for each one.
We don't need a simulation to do that.  To see why not, consider a smaller $n,$ such as $n=3,$ and let $p=1/2$ for simplicity.  We readily compute that the cumulative values $Q$ are $1/8, 1/2, 7/8,$ and $1$ corresponding to $X=0,1,2,3,$ respectively.  These cumulative probabilities occur with frequencies $1/8, 1/2-1/8 = 3/8, 7/8 - 1/2 = 3/8,$ and $1-7/8 = 1/8,$ respectively.  These frequencies for these values of $Q$ are what the code is estimating.
Suppose we were to represent these results as a bar chart (which is what geom_histogram does) using five (say) equally-spaced bins with cutpoints at $0, 1/5, \ldots, 4/5, 1.$

Because the bin $[0, 1/5)$ contains $Q = 1/8$ with a frequency of $1/8,$ the bar for that bin has a height of $1/8.$

Because the bin $[1/5, 2/5)$ does not contain any value of $Q$, the bar for that bin has a height of zero.

Because the bin $[2/5, 3/5)$ contains $Q = 1/2$ with a frequency of $3/8,$ the bar for that bin has a height of $3/8.$

Because the bin $[3/5, 4/5)$ does not contain any value of $Q$, the bar for that bin has a height of zero.

Because the bin $[4/5, 1)$ contains $Q = 7/8$ with a frequency of $3/8,$ the bar for that bin has a height of $3/8.$

Because the bin $[1, 6/5)$ contains $Q = 1$ with a frequency of $1/8,$ the bar for that bin has a height of $1/8.$


Here is the plot (with the bars erected over the left endpoint of each bin):

For reference, the horizontal red line plots the average frequency of $1/5$ (within the interval $[0,1]$ of values).
The bar heights vary from $0$ to $3/8$ in this case.  The unequal spacing and discrete, not perfectly equal frequencies in the bins cause this bar chart not to be uniform.
Use a probability plot to assess uniformity instead.

Because the points follow the reference line, the results are uniform.  The advantage of this plot is that it does not depend on the choice of histogram (or bar plot) cut points.
The bar plot for the situation presented in the question exhibits such non-uniformity, too:

Increasing the number of trials $n$ does not help:

However, coarsening the bins (making them wider) will smooth out the non-uniformity and create a more uniform appearance:

But if you look hard, you can see the heights still vary.  This is real--it's not an artifact of a simulation--because the calculations are accurate and very precise.
For more about the problems and pitfalls of interpreting histograms, please see Glen_B's post at Assessing approximate distribution of data based on a histogram.

This R code performs the calculations and creates the kinds of plots shown here.  Vary the first two lines to experiment.
n_trials <- 1e5         # Number of trials per experiment
p <- 0.3                 # Probability of getting a '1' (success)

x <- seq(0, n_trials)                                   # The possible values
dprobs.log <- dbinom(x, n_trials, p, log = TRUE)
dprobs.log.max <- max(dprobs.log, na.rm = TRUE)
i <- which(dprobs.log - dprobs.log.max > log(2^(-52)))  # Indexes of appreciable values
probs <- pbinom(x[i], n_trials, p)
#
# Compute a histogram.
#
nbins <- max(5, ceiling(100 / 145 * sqrt(n_trials * p * (1 - p))))
library(data.table)
Y <- data.table(Bin = seq(0, nbins))
X <- data.table(P = probs,
                Bin = floor(probs * nbins),
                D = diff(c(0, probs)))
X <- X[, .(P = max(P), D = sum(D)), keyby = .(Bin)]
X <- X[Y, on = "Bin"]
X[, Left := Bin/nbins]
X[, Center := (Bin + 1/2)/nbins]
X[, Right := (Bin + 1)/nbins]
X[is.na(D), D := 0]
(sum(X$D) - 1) # Check
X <- X[zapsmall(D) > 0]
#
# Plot the histogram.
#
w <- min(4, max(1, 300 / nbins))
plot(X$Left, X$D, 
 type = "h", lwd = w, col = gray(0.5),
 xlim = c(0, max(X$Left, 1)),
     ylim = c(0, max(X$D)),
 xlab = "Cumulative probability",
 ylab = "Probability",
 main = "Histogram of Binomial Probabilities")
abline(h = 1/nbins, col = hsv(0.02, .9, .8))
mtext(paste(formatC(n_trials, format = "d", big.mark = ","), 
        "Trials with", nbins, "Bins;",
        "p =", prettyNum(p)), line = 0.25)
#
# Plot the uniform probability plot.
#
plot(probs, probs,
 type = "p",  pch = 21, bg = gray(0.5),
 xlim = c(0, max(X$Left, 1)),
     ylim = c(0, 1),
     xlab = "Cumulative probability",
     ylab = "Cumulative Probability",
     main = "Empirical Plot of Binomial Probabilities")
abline(0:1, col = hsv(0.02, .9, .8), lwd = 2)
mtext(paste(formatC(n_trials, format = "d", big.mark = ","), 
            "Trials with", nbins, "Bins;",
            "p =", prettyNum(p)), line = 0.25)


thanks for elaborating on your comments to my answer. You say that what the OP computed are not p-values. They are indeed cumulative binomial probabilities for the probability of the count observed, or less, under the null. Isnt't that the p-value for a single tailed binomial proportion test, against a null of $p_0=.3$, and an alternative of $p>p_0=.3$. The p-value for such a single-tailed test is exactly this cumulative probability, isn't it? It is not 2-tailed, but??

@jginestet In the absence of any indication of a hypothesis test or even a null hypothesis in the question, one can only speculate.

Nevertheless, whether the OP intended it to be so, or not, these values are p-values for a 1-tailed binomial test. The OP did compute p-values (it may be intentional, or by dumb luck, but the fact remains that he did).

@jginestet By the same argument, virtually any calculation of values of a CDF can be construed to be p-values!

Not of any CDF, of a CDF of a statistic, under the null. And for a single-tailed test. In that case, absolutely. The value at point x of the CDF of the statistic (for the null) is the probability of obtaining $\theta=x$, or lower, and hence is the p-value. Otherwise, if it really were not a p-value, how come, how you brilliantly demonstrated, is the ECDF perfectly uniform (identity line)? That would be quite a coincidence? (the CDF of the binomial being s-shaped, not linear)

@jginestet am having trouble conceiving of any distribution that could not be considered that of a statistic under a null hypothesis, so that distinction looks empty.  Am I missing something?

The $p$-value calculation is designed exactly to compensate for that clustering.  It's a bit clearer, I think, if we use the Normal approximation to pbinom:
$$P(X<x)\approx P\left( Z<\frac{X-x}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}  \right)$$
where $Z$ is a standard Normal distribution ($N(0,1)$).
As you say, $X$ clusters around $np$. Specifically,  $X-x$ is typically around $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ in absolute value.  That means
$$\frac{X-x}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$$
is around 1 in absolute value: the right size to give uniformly distributed $p$-values.  As $n$ increases, $X$ gets relatively more tightly clustered around $np$ (it occupies a smaller and smaller fraction of the possible range), or $X/n$ gets absolutely more tightly clustered around $p$.  The scaling corrects for this, so that the test statistic has the same distribution as $n$ increases, and the $p$-value based on this same distribution stays uniformly distribution.
Basically the same argument is true for the exact test using pbinom, but it's harder to see how the scaling works with a discrete distribution and all the binomial coefficients.

A trivially true answer is that the p-value calculation for a statistical method is designed to yield a uniform distribution under the null hypothesis, but that may not help your understanding. (It is worth noting that some tests yield exactly uniform whereas others can only give approximately uniform.) The reason that a seemingly uniformly distributed p-value can communicate the strength of evidence against the null hypothesis is that the distribution becomes increasingly non-uniform when the 'true' parameter value moves further away from the null hypothesised value. The non-uniformity is in the direction of smaller p-values being more frequent than
large. Thus a small p-value is more likely to be found when the null hypothesis is false than when it is true.
This is a situation where the unusual description of p-values as being like percentiles might be helpful. A p-value times 100 is the percentile ranking of the observed test statistic value within the population  of test statistics possible with the statistical model. (Two tails can be accommodated by ignoring the sign on the test statistic values.) A plot of the frequency of observations falling into the percentile bins will be uniform.

The intuition is actually very simple. Suppose, you have a random variable X with its cumulative distribution function (CDF) F(X). If you sample $x\sim X$ from this distribution then apply CDF to sampled values $s=F(x)$ then you get a sample from the uniform distribution $s\sim Uniform(0,1)$. That's really all to it.
If your null hypothesis holds, it means that you know CDF of the test statistic, then p-values are simply CDF applied to the test statistic. Hence, they are from uniform distribution.
In your example the true distribution (not the null!) is Binom(1000,0.3). You ran 100 experiments, drawing samples from this true distribution. If you apply CDF of binomial distribution to this sample, you'll get a sample from uniform distribution. Now, if your null is true, and p=0.3, then your p-values will be from the uniform too. Here's an example spreadsheet with 2,000 Binomials. The histogram shows the uniform output of true CDF application.


+1 I was waiting for an argument involving the probability integral transform.

@Dave Unfortunately, it's not germane to this thread, which concerns a discrete distribution.  For similar reasons I find half the answers in this thread to be beside the point.

This answer is both incorrect and misleading, because it is implicitly predicated on the assumption that the distribution of the test statistic is continuous, whereas in this case it's specifically the discreteness of that distribution that leads to the strange-looking--and non-uniform--histogram of p-values.
